# Alphabetical order error in C code

Tags: c, crash, compiler-warnings, alphabetical-sort

I have created a program that reads a series of strings from a  .txt file and after compiling a new  .txt file is created where the strings should be in alphabetical order.The problem is that I can't write more than 10 words, the compiler just stops/crashes, WHY? Does it depend by the type of compiler? I am currently using Code-Bloks.How can I optimize the code to run more smoothly?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void arrange(int n, char *x[])
{
    char *temp;
    int i,str;
    for(str = 0; str < n-1; ++str)
    {
        for(i = str+1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if(strcmp(x[str],x[i]) > 0)
            {
                temp = x[str];
                x[str] = x[i];
                x[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
int  number_of_lines = 0;
void countOfLinesFromFile(char *filename){
FILE* myfile = fopen(filename, "r");
int ch;
do
{
    ch = fgetc(myfile);
    if(ch == '\n')
        number_of_lines++;
}
while (ch != EOF);
if(ch != '\n' && number_of_lines != 0)
    number_of_lines++;
    fclose(myfile);
return number_of_lines;
}
int main()
{
    int i , ts=0;
    char *x[10];
    char *fileName = "WORDS.txt";
    countOfLinesFromFile(fileName);
    printf("%d",number_of_lines);
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen ("WORDS.txt", "r");
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (char*) malloc (1200*sizeof(char));
        fscanf(fp, "%s", x[i]);
    }
    FILE *fPointer;
    fPointer=fopen("Alphabetical.txt","w+");
    arrange(i,x);
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fPointer,"%s\n",x[i]);
    }
    fclose(fPointer);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C, not C#.

Comment: Compiler warnings are the first line of defence against simple logic errors. For example you should be receiving "warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void" from `void countOfLinesFromFile(char *filename)`

Comment: @AestheticCode If your question was adequately answered you can mark it as resolved by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most useful.

Answer (score 2):

char *x[10];

The buffer size is too small

Answer (score 1):

These two lines define how much information you can store

```
char *x[10];                               // 10 strings
x[i] = (char*) malloc (1200*sizeof(char)); // 1200 characters each
```

As it is written now, you can only hold a maximum of 10 strings with each string being no longer than 1200 characters.

---

The crash is caused when `number_of_lines >= 11` in the following for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++)
{
    x[i] = (char*) malloc (1200*sizeof(char));
    fscanf(fp, "%s", x[i]);
}
```

When `i` is 11 you write to `x[11]` which is past the end of `x`.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1, so it's never needed. Also, the cast (char*) is redundant.

Comment: @BjornA. I am quoting the code from the question to point out where the error occurs.

Comment: I would also argue that `sizeof(char)` is better because it shows the intent behind 1, rather than a meaningless magic number.

Comment: Basically `x[i] = malloc(1200 * sizeof(char))` shows that `x[i]` is a string vs. `x[i] = malloc(1200)` which is vague and leaves the reader with extra work to determine what `x[i]` actually holds.

Comment: If you have the option of being more or less explicit with little or no extra cost might as as well opt to be more explicit.

Comment: yeah, but that's a false dichotomy. Better solutions exist, and all magic numbers suck. 
x[i] = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN); is better than both (1200) and (1200 * sizeof(char);

Comment: I agree there are better solutions, but `malloc(n * sizeof(char)) ` > `malloc(n)`.

Comment: But malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN) > malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN * sizeof(char)) ;)